# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: rango_category.super_cat_id

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

```
/*tests.py*/
def create_user(username, password):
user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
return user

#helper function to populat database 
def create_category(name, super, user):
category = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
category.super = super
category.user = user
category.save()
return category

# The following test is for the save and deleting of
# a page from the favorites list
class TestFavoritesFeature(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.user = create_user("testUser", "testPassword")
    self.cat = create_category('python', self.super, self.user)
```

Both the object.create and object.get_or_create give an error for NOT NULL field. Above is the code , 2 models and both throw an error on only the id field that we do not even populate. It is the function's job to assign a unique id to it. The above is code from tests.py file. I am trying to populate DB for unit testing . In the actual code, these objects.get_or_create or objects.create do not give errors but are rather successful

Comment: shouldn't you use `self.client.get(...,{'page_id': self.page.id})` so with `page_id` over `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [**`.get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) you need to provide values for the `super_cat`, `user` and `name`, but you only did this for the name.

We can further simplify the method by using [**`.update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) and use the `defaults=…` parameter to specify what to update or initialize in case the object is not/is created:

```
def create_category(name, super, user):
    category, __ = Category.objects.update_or_create(
        name=name,
        defaults={'super_cat': super, 'user': user}
    )
    return category
```

Comment: Yes thanks it works. Now I have a manyToManyField, it is not allowing me to pass in in defaults as a key value pair. how do I go on about adding it ?

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: you will need to update that in the lines after `category, __ = ...` and `return category`. There you can use `category.yourm2mfield.add(some_item)`, etc.

Comment: When I try response = self.client.get(url) while unit testing. I get the message that anonymous user not acceptable

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: you will need to login first, and might also be useful to add a guard on the function such that you do not create a `Category` if no user is given.

Comment: Yes logged in . Now I have an issue with self.client.get
I do 
            self.response = self.client.get(reverse('rango:save_favorite')
But, it appears that it is not executing the view related to the save favorite because in the view I save an item to the DB. When I try to assert the item was added it fails

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: A GET request should have *no* side effects. You should only update entities with a POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE request: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/a-get-request-with-side-effects.html If a GET request has side-effects, then that violates the HTTP protocol.

Comment: What is a side effect in get request , how I know I have one ?

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: If you modify something at the database side, write to a file, or in any other way change the program state (or the state of some third party application). In other words, doing the GET request zero, one, or multiple times, should not have impact on the results of (other) queries.

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: can you share the testcase together with the view that is supposed to implement the logic. Please *edit* the question.

Comment: Yes, Just updated the code . Look at the view and the test case I added at the end. 

I am doing a get request because the result need to be updated on the UI dynamically. So as you can see in the SaveFavoriteView I am making use of the HttpResponse to do that . Can I send a response to the UI with a post request as well?

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: well that is violating the HTTP protocol. You can make POST requests through AJAX since a POST requests *can* (and nearly always *do*) make changes to the entities and the state of the application, etc. See section 9 of the HTTP protocol: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: here I listed some problems with GET requests with side effects (besides not being HTTP compliant, it can also result in data loss for example): https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/a-get-request-with-side-effects.html

Comment: Thanks but can I use HttpResponse from a post request from inside the view so that way some response is sent back to the UI or is the only option to re render the page ?

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: no, the `post` method can for example return a `JsonResponse`, or any other response. The `post` method should eventually return a (subclass) of a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/
Here they say in django post are only for form data.

Comment: @NikhitaSareen: now, it does not say that a POST request is only handling form data it says that `request.POST` (the `POST` attribute of the `request`) is handling only form data, and thus that in POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests, you should use `request.data` instead of `request.POST` to implement POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests.

Comment: Based on the fact that you inherit from `View`, you are not defining an API with the Django REST framework (DRF). It might be better to work with DRF, since it can implement `ViewSet`s and thus implement the basic CRUD of most entities with a small amount of logic.

Comment: Can you please look at this issue also.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679088/alueerror-cannot-assign-value-field-must-be-a-object-instance