# alueError: Cannot assign value-field-must-be-a-object-instance

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "(<UP:testUser>, True)": "C.pI" must be a "UP" instance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns tuple:

```
profile, _ = UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(gender = 'F',
                                           defaults={
                                           'user': user})
```

`profile` is your user, `_` is boolean if it was created or updated.

Comment: Yea, right. So but, then why would it throw the error ? It is clearly saying it created UserProfile and then giving a value error along with it .

Comment: @NikhitaSareen it's saying you try to assign `(<UserProfile: testUser>, True)` which is a tuple, you need `<UserProfile: testUser>`

Comment: Just update `create_user_profile` with what I wrote above and it will work.